# Localhost pinging when there is no network card

Tags: network-adapter, ping, window, dell-vostro

How it is possible to ping localhost when there is no network card.
[image]

Comment: localhost is an internal IP address, which is handled directly by the kernel. No external network is involved (thus no network card). Is is used to handle "network" connections to the same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loopback adaptor has nothing to do with any physical hardware: it's a service provided internally by the operating system.